# Treeview Item with children nodes of different types

Tags: wpf, treeview

I have three classes that I wish to represent in a treeview

```
public class ConfiguratorObjectViewModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    
    public string Id { get; set; }
        
    public string ParentId { get; set; }
    
    public ObservableCollection<ConfiguratorAttributeViewModel> Attributes { get; set; } 
        
    public ObservableCollection<ConfiguratorObjectFamilyViewModel> Children { get; set; }   
}
```

```
public class ConfiguratorObjectFamilyViewModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    
    public string Id { get; set; }
        
    public string ParentId { get; set; }
        
    public ObservableCollection<ConfiguratorObjectViewModel> ConfiguratorObjects { get; set; }  
}
```

```
public class ConfiguratorAttributeViewModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    
    public string Id { get; set; }
        
    public string ParentId { get; set; }    
}
```

Here is my treeview template

```
<TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding RootObject}" >
    <TreeView.Resources>
    
    <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:ConfiguratorObjectFamilyViewModel}" ItemsSource="{Binding ConfiguratorObjects}">
            <local:ConfiguratorObjectTreeItem  />
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    
     <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:ConfiguratorObjectViewModel}" ItemsSource="{Binding }" Children>
            <local:ConfiguratorObjectTreeItem  />
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>   

    </TreeView.Resources>

</TreeView>
```

This template gives me all `ConfiguratorObjectFamily` and all `ConfoguratorObject` items. How do I extend this so that `ConfiguratorAttribute` items should be included in the tree?

I have tried extending the templates by adding combinations of the following to no avail...

```
<HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:ConfiguratorAttributeViewModel}" ItemsSource="{Binding Attributes}" >
    <local:ConfiguratorObjectTreeItem  />
</HierarchicalDataTemplate>
```

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:ConfiguratorAttributeViewModel}" >
    <local:ConfiguratorObjectTreeItem  />
</DataTemplate>
```

Note that the `ConfiguratorAttributeViewModel` is not a hierarchy

Comment: I found a solution by using a composite collection. However, I do not know if this is the optimal solution in this case ...

Comment: Alternatively you could merge the collections into a collection of type `object` e.g., `ObservableCollection<object>`. However, you end up with a mixed collection that requires sorting if you want to group the different types. To avoid the sorting you can override the default template of the `TreeViewItem` to add a second `ItemsControl` next to the existing to display the second data type that is not part of the hierarchy.

Comment: Also, if you say that the `ConfiguratorAttributeViewModel` is not part of the hierarchy you should consider to display it separately in a second `ListBox` and create a master-detail relationship between the `TreeView` and this `ListBox`. `TreeView` goes to the left column of the layout and the `ListBox` to right.

Comment: Now, selecting a `ConfiguratorObjectViewModel` node in the `TreeView` will show the associated `ConfiguratorAttributeViewModel` items in the `ListBox` view. Simply bind the `ListBox` to the `SelectedItem` of the `TreeView` and use a converter to check the type of the selected item (if it is a `ConfiguratorObjectViewModel`) and return the `Attributes` property value to feed the `ListBox` or an empty collection if the selected node is not a `ConfiguratorObjectViewModel`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution by using a composite collection.

```
public IList Items
{
  get
  {
    return new CompositeCollection()
    {
      new CollectionContainer() { Collection = Children },
      new CollectionContainer() { Collection = Attributes }
    };
  }
}
```

And the template as such:

```
<HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:ConfiguratorObjectViewModel}" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" >
    <local:ConfiguratorObjectTreeItem  />
</HierarchicalDataTemplate>

<HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:ConfiguratorObjectFamilyViewModel}" ItemsSource="{Binding ConfiguratorObjects}">
    <local:ConfiguratorObjectTreeItem  />
</HierarchicalDataTemplate>

<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:ConfiguratorAttributeViewModel}" >
    <local:ConfiguratorObjectTreeItem  />
</DataTemplate>
```